# Using oAuth in API throwing internal server error

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, authentication, oauth

[My application](https://stackapps.com/questions/7711/microsoft-prod-stack-exchange-internal-placeholder) has 26 users, but yesterday several (prospective) users started receiving an error page (/error?aspxerror=/oauth) saying that it is all [stack exchange's] fault and that the data is logged.

Is there any way for me to view that information? Is oAuth currently broken for approving users to new applications?

Answer (score 3):

Today I learned an exciting new deficiency in ASP.NET MVC <= 5; child actions cannot be asynchronous -_-

A fix has been deployed.

This bug was introduced as part of some work underway that modernized the OAuth flow's backend.